# Find a way out of the maze

Tags: javascript

II need to write an algorithm to find a way out of the maze, which is 2-dimensional array. I played with the code, but can't it fully understand how should I mark in the code the finish line when no more pluses left and that is a way from the maze?
`0` - start position
`+` - way
`#` - wall.

Am I on the right track? Is a recursive function is a good approach for this challenge?

```
var maze = [
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '+', '+', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '+', '#', '0', '#', '+', '+', '+', '+'],
  ['#', '#', '+', '+', '+', '+', '+', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '+', '+', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '+', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '+', '#', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '+', '+', '#', '#'],
  ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
];
```

I played with the code but still can't get it fully? Am I on the right way? Is recursive function can be the solution for this challenge? I am very thankful to everybody who can help me.

My 'not perfect code' :)

```
function goFurther(row, column) {

  console.log(maze[row][column]);
  if (maze[row][column] == ' ') {
    console.log('We solved the maze');
  } else if (maze[row][column] == '+') {
    console.log('you need make it go further');
    maze[row][column] = 909;
    if (row < maze.length - 1) {
      goFurther(row + 1, column);
    }
    if (column < maze[row].length - 1) {
      goFurther(row, column + 1);
    }

    if (row > 0) {
      goFurther(column + 1, row);
      console.log(row, column);
    }
    if (column > 0) {
      goFurther(row + 1, column);
      console.log(row, column);
    }
  }
}

goFurther(2, 2);
```

Comment: _"Am I on the right track?"_ - Maybe.  _"Is a recursive function is a good approach for this challenge?"_ - It's one possibility. _"Is recursive function is the solution for this challenge?"_ - Ask the author of the challenge.

Comment: Depth-first search (what you're trying) will work, but it might take a while...

Comment: `Is recursive function can be the solution for this challenge?`  recursion (no matter for which task) is most of the time the naïve solution, which can work but might not be the solution a challenge is looking for.

Comment: Thanks , now I know that I am on a right  way, everything is so new for me)

Comment: There are two most-common methods for answering this kind of question and they are *depth first* and *breadth first* searches. Depth first usually uses recursion and that's what you've used here. Breadth first usually uses a counter or weights and a loop. For a better understanding, look up either on youtube. They are common topics and very well explained on there.

Comment: @LaytonGB Both _depth first_ and  _breadth first_ can be implemented recursive or non-recursive. The algorithm (no matter if it is recursive or no recursive) for  _depth first_ and  _breadth first_  is mostly the same only the point when you look at the element is at a different point in the algorithm. For most languages you don't want to use recursion due to the way function calls are implemented (stack limit) which makes it hard to predict how deep recursion can be before you application crashes.